# How to create submit form in a row and relate input to that row?

Tags: php, mysql

**Hey Guys, I have a question for you.**

Imagine that I wanted to be able to keep track of how many miles I've ran every week, so that I could
compare it to the goals I've set for each week. So i've created this table by the use of mysql_fetch_row.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM randomtable ORDER BY week ASC");

echo "<Table id='result' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr class='toprow'>
    <th>Week</th>
    <th>Goal</th>
    <th>Actual Number of Miles</th>
    </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr class='standardrow'>";
    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
    echo "<td><form><input method='post' type='number'></form></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

This piece of code resultet in a table with 10 weeks with 10 goals - and a column for the actual number of miles. This column should include 10 input forms where the actual number of miles can be submitted. But how do I relate the input from the submit form to the row in which the submit form is positioned?
The primary key is the week - so this would be the one to relate to.

Hope you understand what my problem is:)

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="rowvalue" value="$row[1]" />`

Answer (score 1):

To do this you would use a [hidden input field](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms07.htm).

When you `echo` each row, and the form in that row, you would simply add an extra line:

```
`<input type="hidden" name="row_id" value="' . $row['id_column'] . '" />';
```

In full, your code would be:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM randomtable ORDER BY week ASC");

echo "<Table id='result' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr class='toprow'>
    <th>Week</th>
    <th>Goal</th>
    <th>Actual Number of Miles</th>
    </tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr class='standardrow'>";
    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
    echo "<td>
            <form>
                <input method='post' type='number'>
                <input type='hidden' name='row_id' value='" . $row['id_column'] . "' />
            </form>
          </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Hey - thank you for the answer! - but when I try to insert what you've written i returns: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' on line xx". Furthermore - how do I e.g. update the value through mysql?

Comment: @user2332325 You would use PHP to retrieve the form data, and from there you would retrieve the `row_id` that was passed and then do something like: `Update table, set column= 'some data' where row = $rowID`

Comment: Allright, so how would i retrieve the form data and so forth through PHP? I'm kind of stuck. If I've called the row with weeks, week in my database?

Comment: @user2332325 Look up `post data in php` for sending and retrieving the values. You'll need to do some reading up on PHP before you continue

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be some modifications that has to be done in loop.

```
echo "<td><form  method='post'><input type='number' value='".$rows['col_name']."'><input type='submit' ></form></td>";
```

This code adds a submit button to each row. But, this shouldn't be what I think.
It should be rather this way,

```
echo "<form  method='post'> ";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr class='standardrow'>";
    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='number' value='".$rows['col_name']."'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' ></form>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Or make the input field look like this.

```
'<input type="text" name="row['.$row['id_column'].'][miles]" />';
```

It will return you an array when you post it.

```
foreach($_POST['row'] as $key => $value){
// $key is your primary key
// $value['miles'] is your input value
}
```